# Why is this command not working in Python when attempting to display a MySql database

Tags: python, mysql

```
cursor = conn.cursor(dictionary=True)
show_table = """
SELECT 
itemdescription, 
quantity, 
dateadded
FROM 
shoppinglistTest2;
"""
execute_query(conn, show_table)
cursor.execute(show_table)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for user in rows:
   print(user)
```

I am using python to connect to a MySql database and display the tables with these attributes but I get this error after the table is created and data is already there

```
The error 'Unread result found' occurred
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rhythm/Documents/CIS 3368/Shopping test 2", line 29, in <module>
    cursor.execute(show_table)
```

UPDATE:
I found that if I just add an item to the list then I get the list printed

```
item_des = 'Pie'
item_quant = 2
item_added = datetime.date.today()
query = "INSERT INTO shoppinglistTest2 (itemdescription, quantity, dateadded) VALUES ('%s', %s, '%s')" % (item_des,     item_quant, item_added)
execute_query(conn, query)
cursor = conn.cursor(dictionary=True)
run = """
SELECT 
itemdescription, 
quantity, 
dateadded
FROM 
shoppinglistTest2;
"""
cursor.execute(run)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for user in rows:
    print(user)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the following:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
show_table = """
SELECT 
itemdescription, 
quantity, 
dateadded
FROM 
shoppinglistTest2;
"""
cursor.execute(show_table)
for itemdescription, quantity, dateaddedin in cursor.fetchall():
   print(itemdescription)
   print(quantity)
   print(dateaddedin )
```

Comment: I did and it didn't give me an error. But for every item it only returned the words itemdescription, quantity, dateadded

Comment: Could you show me what you have in your shoppinglistTest2 table. Do you use workbench, phpmyadmin or just shell to interract with the mysql? What output do you expect? ```print(itemdescription)``` should print whatever value is assigned to itemdescription column unless you do  ```print("itemdescription")``` . Just out of curiosity, try removing dictionary=True flag

Comment: insert ignore into shoppinglistTest2(itemdescription, quantity, dateadded)
values
('Bananas',20,'2021-09-30'),

Comment: Removing dictionary = true gave me an error 'AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'execute''

Comment: Sorry I'm still new to the website and programming in general

Comment: Thats good. First of all, insert statement will not insert anything unless you commit first. Do you have auto commit flag set to True? If you do not, then you must manually commit after you execute the query. Also, there should be no reason why you would want to use dictionary=True unless you really know that you need it. Is your table empty at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you call `execute_query()` before `cursor.execute()` without reading the results from the query, which MySQL connector does not like

Comment: even after swiping the places I still get that error

Comment: Swapping places like how? You apparently still dont read all the results in between. Why do you even need to call both these functions when they do the same thing?

Comment: I figured it out a different way, sorry about that.

Comment: the question remains - why are you executing the query twice? And if you found a solution, maybe post it as an answer, so if someone else would encounter the same problem & find your post, they can read a useful answer instead of "I figured it out a different way"